How do I check when my video was uploaded instead of when it was published?
I have a video I uploaded as private. I then scheduled the video to go public a few months later. Now that the video is public, YouTube's video manager shows me the video's published date (when it went public) instead of the date it was initially uploaded.
How do I check when my video was initially uploaded to YouTube instead of the date it was published?


To see when a video was initially uploaded, you can check the video analytics in YouTube Studio and display "Since uploaded (lifetime)".

Open YouTube Studio
Select the "Content" icon in the left sidebar
Find the video you want to check and click the "Analytics" icon
Click the time range in the top right and select "Since uploaded (lifetime)"
The initial upload date will be displayed as the first item on the view timeline in the bottom left and as the start of the date range in the top right


